# Getting error (numpy.ndarray' object is not callable) while running following code in Jupyter

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook

**Checking Robustness of the model**
In this section we will check robustness of our LSTM model. I have used new unseen datasets for this from July 1, 2017 to July 20,2017. I have downloaded the data sets from google finance website to check for robustness of the model.

```
import preprocess_data as ppd

data = pd.read_csv('E:/DBSOM DATA\FOM_Sem 2/Analyses of S&U Data/Project work/Stock-Price-Prediction- 
master/googl.csv')

stocks = ppd.remove_data(data)

stocks = ppd.get_normalised_data(stocks)

stocks = stocks.drop(['Item'], axis = 1)
#Print the dataframe head and tail
print(stocks.head())

#X = stocks[:].as_matrix()
#Y = stocks[:]['Close'].as_matrix()
X = stocks[:].values()
Y = stocks[:]['Close'].values()

X = sd.unroll(X,1)
Y = Y[-X.shape[0]:]

print(X.shape)
print(Y.shape)

# Generate predictions 
predictions = model.predict(X)

#get the test score
testScore = model.evaluate(X, Y, verbose=0)
print('Test Score: %.4f MSE (%.4f RMSE)' % (testScore, math.sqrt(testScore)))
```

Comment: Which line is the error on? Can you paste the full error message in the question, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.values` property shouldn't have `()`:

```
X = stocks[:].values
Y = stocks[:]['Close'].values
```

Note: the [documentation for `.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) says that `.values` is no longer recommended, and recommends using [`.to_numpy()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy) instead.

Comment: thanks I have used .to_numpy() but now I am getting another error: 

Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.

Comment: Again, which line? In any case, the error is telling you that you have a three-dimensional array where the routine in question expected a two-dimensional or one-dimensional one.

Comment: I have posted this as a separate question. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63594972/getting-error-found-array-with-dim-3-estimator-expected-2-while-running-fo