# Getting Error (Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2) while running following code

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, data-science

**Checking Robustness of the model:**
In this section I will check robustness of my LSTM model. I have used new unseen datasets for this from July 1, 2017 to July 20,2017. I have downloaded the data sets from google finance website to check for robustness of the model.

```
import preprocess_data as ppd
data = pd.read_csv('E:/DBSOM DATA\FOM_Sem 2/Analyses of S&U Data/Project work/Stock-Price-Prediction-master/googl.csv')
stocks = ppd.remove_data(data)
stocks = ppd.get_normalised_data(stocks)
stocks = stocks.drop(['Item'], axis = 1)

#Print the data frame head and tail

print(stocks.head())
X = stocks[:].values
Y = stocks[:]['Close'].values
X = sd.unroll(X,1)
Y = Y[-X.shape[0]:]

print(X.shape)
print(Y.shape)

# Generate predictions 

predictions = model.predict(X)

#get the test score

testScore = model.evaluate(X, Y, verbose=0)
print('Test Score: %.4f MSE (%.4f RMSE)' % (testScore, math.sqrt(testScore)))
```

**Functions definitions**

```
import pandas as pd
Import sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

def get_normalised_data(data):
    
    # Initialize a scaler, then apply it to the features
    
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    numerical = ['Open', 'Close', 'Volume']
    data[numerical] = scaler.fit_transform(data[numerical])
    return data

def remove_data(data):

    # Define columns of data to keep from historical stock data

    item = []
    open = []
    close = []
    volume = []

    # Loop through the stock data objects backwards and store factors we want to keep

    i_counter = 0
    for i in range(len(data) - 1, -1, -1):
        item.append(i_counter)
        open.append(data['Open'][i])
        close.append(data['Close'][i])
        volume.append(data['Volume'][i])
        i_counter += 1

    # Create a data frame for stock data
    stocks = pd.DataFrame()

    # Add factors to data frame

    stocks['Item'] = item
    stocks['Open'] = open
    stocks['Close'] = pd.to_numeric(close)
    stocks['Volume'] = pd.to_numeric(volume)

    # return new formatted data
    return stocks
```

I have invested a lot of time resolving this error, but does not find solution. Please suggest.

Comment: Update: I have used .to_numpy() instead of .values but same error.

Comment: Would you mind providing the full Traceback?

Comment: never mind I have solved this issue myself. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I removed this line Import sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler

And volla. Everything runs smoothly.